# Java Enums: List enumerated values from a Class<? extends Enum>

Tags: java, enums

I've got the class object for an enum (I have a `Class<? extends Enum>`) and I need to get a list of the enumerated values represented by this enum. The `values` static function has what I need, but I'm not sure how to get access to it from the class object.

Comment: its static - reflection.

Comment: `Class` is a reflection object (it predates the package).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

[`Class.getEnumConstants`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants())

Answer (score 24):

If you know the name of the value you need:

```
     Class<? extends Enum> klass = ... 
     Enum<?> x = Enum.valueOf(klass, "NAME");
```

If you don't, you can get an array of them by (as Tom got to first):

```
     klass.getEnumConstants();
```

Answer (score 18):

I am suprised to see that [`EnumSet#allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-) is not mentioned:

> `public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> allOf(Class<E> elementType)`
>   Creates an enum set containing all of the elements in the specified element type.

Consider the following `enum`:

```
enum MyEnum {
  TEST1, TEST2
}
```

Simply call the method like this:

```
Set<MyEnum> allElementsInMyEnum = EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class);
```

Of course, this returns a `Set`, not a `List`, but it should be enough in many (most?) use cases.

Or, if you have an unknown `enum`:

```
Class<? extends Enum> enumClass = MyEnum.class;
Set<? extends Enum> allElementsInMyEnum = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass);
```

The advantage of this method, compared to [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--), is that it is typed so that it is not possible to pass anything other than an `enum` to it. For example, the below code is valid and returns `null`:

```
String.class.getEnumConstants();
```

While this won't compile:

```
EnumSet.allOf(String.class); // won't compile
```

Comment: It looks like this method is going to be way faster. The reflection method clones a shared array that's built using reflection and the security API. The `EnumSet` uses a "bit vector" stored in a `long`.

Answer (score 15):

using **reflection** is simple as calling [Class#getEnumConstants()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29):

```
List<Enum<?>> enum2list(Class<? extends Enum<?>> cls) {
   return Arrays.asList(cls.getEnumConstants());
}
```