# Java generics type

Tags: java, generics, enums

Consider the code below...

```
public class Test {

    public interface I {}
    public enum E1 implements I {M, N}
    public enum E2 implements I {O, P}
    public static class A<T extends Enum<T> & I> {
        void test() {
            // how to print the enum constants here ?
            System.out.println("... ");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A<E2> {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        A<E1> a = new A<E1>();
        B b = new B();

        a.test();
        b.test();
    }
}
```

How to access the `T` class in `test` ? e.g. how to print the enum constants ?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626901/java-enums-list-enumerated-values-from-a-class-extends-enum

Comment: Why do you need to be able to list the values for an enum, anyway?

Comment: @AJMansfield LOL! :-)

Comment: You could add to the constructor of A and hold onto a Class<T> object and use that to get the enum constants.

Comment: @thelost No, seriously. If you feel like you need to do that, you should probably be using an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to handle that.

Comment: @TimB thanks, but that's not the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately those generic informations for case A are not available in runtime. You have to use [type token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) pattern. In case B you can use "hack" to get constants:

```
    void test() {
        Type superclass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (ParameterizedType.class.isAssignableFrom(superclass.getClass())) {
            ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) superclass;
            Class enumClass = (Class) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            for (Object o : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
                System.out.println(o);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Comment: I've added type check (it thrown class cast in A case)

Comment: thanks! How could I get this work with another `C` extending `B` ? ie. bubble up the enum

Comment: In this case you have to manually get the supeclass and operate on its generic information: this.getClass().getSuperclass().getGenericSuperclass()

Comment: Given that the type parameter is available, using it gives you a far easier solution that does not use excessive reflection.

Answer (score 1):

It is instructive to consider how to write your program without generics. Any program that can be written with generics can also be turned into an equivalent program without generics by simply removing the type parameters and inserting casts in the appropriate places. (Ignoring a few things like generics in the metadata of classes, which is not relevant here.) This is called *type erasure*.

```
public class Test {

    public interface I {}
    public enum E1 implements I {M, N}
    public enum E2 implements I {O, P}
    public static class A {
        void test() {
            // how to print the enum constants here ?
            System.out.println("... ");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.test();
        b.test();
    }
}
```

If your program cannot be written without generics, it cannot be written with generics either.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason to create a type parameterized type and then not use the parameterized type? Use the parameterized type and take a look at the javadoc for `java.lang.Class` and it is straightforward to implement, here is one way to do it.

```
public class Test {

    public interface I { }
    public enum E1 implements I {M, N}
    public enum E2 implements I {O, P}
    public static class A<T extends Enum<T> & I> {
        void test(Class<T> ct) {
            for(T t: ct.getEnumConstants()) {
                System.out.println("... " + t);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A<E2> {}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        A<E1> a = new A<E1>();
        B b = new B();

        System.out.println("Using E1");
        a.test(E1.class);
        System.out.println("Using E2");
        b.test(E2.class);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Using E1
... M
... N
Using E2
... O
... P
```

Comment: So why would I do `new A<E1>()` and then `a.test(E1.class);` ?

Comment: The first is a type parameter and the second is a method argument. When you do `new A<E1>()` you cannot invoke `a.test` with `E2` like so `a.test(E2.class)`

I suggest picking up a good book on generics to getting you up to speed, `Java Generics and Collections` is a good start.

If you have down voted my answer, can you explain to me why? I would like to know if the answer is just "I do not understand what you have coded" or something more that might be useful for me to learn.

Comment: The thing is that I would not like to have to specify the class again, but infer it from the type

Comment: `Types` are different from `Type parameters`. The code as you have written in your question make no use of the `Type parameter`, you could remove it entirely and it would make no difference, if that is what you desired, the reflective solution is the way to go, and you lose the benefits of the type system.