# Iterate Over Array of Enum Classes in Java, Testing `parse()` Method of Each

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, enums

I'm trying to be efficient in writing some Junit tests for my Java Enum classes, and testing the `parse()` method of each.  Here's an example of doing it one at a time for the `FileFormatCodeEnum`:

```
@Test
public void testFileFormatCodeEnum() {

    FileFormatCodeEnum[] ens = FileFormatCodeEnum.values();
    for(FileFormatCodeEnum en : ens) {
        Assert.assertEquals(FileFormatCodeEnum.parse(en.getValue()), en);
    }
}
```

Since every Enum class in my project has a `parse()` method, I'd prefer not to write this same code for every one of them by replacing the class name everywhere it's found.

I'd like to do something more like this:

```
@Test
public void testAllEnums() {
    ArrayList<Class> allEnums = new ArrayList<Class>();
    allEnums.add(FileFormatCodeEnum.class);
    allEnums.add(RoleTypeCodeEnum.class);

    //begin some pseudo-code here
    for (Class clazz : allEnums) {
        //TODO: get clazz.values() of the enum into an array named 'ens'
        for(Generic en : ens) {
            //cast the generic enum to a specific enum type maybe?
            //then execute the parse method on the specific enum
            Assert.assertEquals(SpecificEnum.parse(en.getValue()), en);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to use reflection (?) to achieve this.

Anyone know if there's a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class to store a "test pair" - the list of all enums, and a function to parse their textual values:

```
class TestEnum {
    private final List<Enum> values;
    private final Function<String,Enum> parse;
    public TestEnum(List<Enum> v, Function<String,Enum> p) {
        values = v;
        parse = p;
    }
    public List<Enum> getValues() { return values; }
    public Function<String,Enum> getParse() { return parse; }
}
List<TestEnum> allEnums = Arrays.asList(
    new TestEnum(Arrays.asList(FileFormatCodeEnum.values()), s -> FileFormatCodeEnum.parse(s))
,   new TestEnum(Arrays.asList(RoleTypeCodeEnum.values()), s -> RoleTypeCodeEnum.parse(s))
);
```

Now you can go through all enums and test their `parse` method like this:

```
for (TestEnum t : allEnums) {
    for (Enum v : t.getValues()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(t.getParse().apply(v.toString()), v);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/iAeWij)

Comment: Thanks for this response! I'm working on implementing it now, and I'm likely to accept once I get it in place to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `t.getEnumConstants()`, [as per this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626977/679240)

```
@Test
public void testAllEnums() {
    ArrayList<Class> allEnums = new ArrayList<Class>();
    allEnums.add(FileFormatCodeEnum.class);
    allEnums.add(RoleTypeCodeEnum.class);

    //begin some pseudo-code here
    for (Class<Generic> clazz : allEnums) {
        for(Generic en : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            Assert.assertEquals(SpecificEnum.parse(en.getValue()), en);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the code above supposes the enums implement the `Generic` interface (or whatever interface you may want to use), and that this interface has a `.parse()` method.

Comment: The enums are just basic enums, i.e., `public enum FileFormatCodeEnum { ... }`, so unfortunately this approach won't work.

Answer (score -1):

What you are searching for is this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Take a look at Method class, and specially its "invoke" method, which lets you invoke a method of an object without knowing its class at compile time.

Comment: That's a good idea. However, an acceptable *answer* would have to point me to a workable solution rather than an area of exploration. I appreciate your comment though.

Comment: You did research and mentioned a guiding link. You could cite important parts and __explain how to leverage reflection__ to find and execute the `parse()` method from each enum-class. Otherwise it's not an [answer] and should be __posted as comment instead__.